# Android AlarmManager service without wakeup

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am writing an Android service that checks a website every day at 5 PM. If certain conditions are met it will raise a Notification, if not then nothing should happen.

At first I tried to implement it as a background service that would start a thread that sleeps for the number of milliseconds until the next 5 PM, then do the check and raise the notification if needed, and then go back to sleep again.
This worked if I was close to 5 PM when the service was started, but not otherwise and I have learnt after googling that Android can kill a service at any time, so I guess this is not the recommended solution.

The recommendations I find seems to all point to the AlarmManager, which was also what I first looked at before implementing the above solution, but there is one drawback with it. If I use RTC as type, then the check won't be performed until the user starts to use the phone, I want it to be done even if idle. However, I don't want to use RTC_WAKEUP because I don't want the screen to turn on unless I conclude that the notification should be raised.

I guess it should be doable as it is exactly what any email-application does. The screen doesn't come on every minute if that is how often the email service checks the server for new messages.

Does RTC_WAKEUP really turn on the screen? If yes, is there another preferred technique for implementing the above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I don't want to use RTC_WAKEUP because I don't want the screen to turn on unless I conclude that the notification should be raised.

`RTC_WAKEUP` does not turn on the screen.

> Does RTC_WAKEUP really turn on the screen?

No. Here, it only "wakes up" the CPU.